# Making textarea display the same in WebKit as in other browsers

Tags: css, webkit, textarea

Webkit decided there weren't enough browser incompatibilities and added 2px of padding to my textarea.  However, if I set padding:0 then it looks awful when typed in.  Is there a way I can make it the same size without destroying the display?  (It seems like -webkit-padding-start:2px and -webkit-padding-start:2px will fix the left and right, but there are not corresponding properties for the top and bottom)

Also, there's some type of little handle in the bottom right corner to allow resizing of the textarea.  Any idea what CSS property might turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part of your question try this:

```
textarea
{
  resize:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem myself. Try:

```
<textarea style="margin-left:0;">
```